# Android webview giving blank screen when loading data from HTTPS

Tags: android

I have a problem with an URL that starts with https. It's showing a blank white screen whereas links, starting with http, loads successfully in Android webview.

With logs I'm sure that data is coming from HTTPS also but is not displaying in the view. Please help me. Some sample code or link will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI,
I read your question, I don't know what is your exact issue if you have data then you can use these line of code to display it in webview

encoding contains html tags like <p> aadfasdf asdf ds </p>

public static final String HTML_FORMAT =
          "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\">" +
          "<html><head><title></title>"+
          "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
          "'body {color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#000000;font-size: 10pt}'" +
          "</style>" +
          "</head>" +
          "<body>" +
          "%s" +
          "</body></html>";

String textHtml = String.format(Constants.HTML_FORMAT,encoding);

wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, textHtml, "text/html","utf-8", null);

try this hopefully you will get your required result.

Comment: thanks for help but it not a fit solution , i have edited my question.